# Test if all characters in string are not alphanumeric

Tags: regex, string, stata

The string below is probably the result of bad API call:

```
_±êµÂ’¥÷“_¡“__‘_Ó ’¥Ï“ùü’ÄÛ“_« “_Ô“ÜÂ“ù÷ “Ïã“_÷’¥Ï “µÏ“ÄÅ“ù÷ “Á¡ê±«“ùã ê¡Û“_ã “__’
```

I am not sure which rows contain non-alphanumeric characters and my task is to identify which rows are problematic.

Another problem is that some non-alphanumeric characters appear with strings that I would like to still keep and search, like:

```
This sentence is fine and searchable, but a few non-alphanumeric äóî donäó»t popup
```

Is there a way to test if the entire contents of a string are non-alphanumeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find all rows with only standard alphabetic and numeric characters including commas, periods, exclamation and question marks as well as spaces:

```
clear
input str168 var1
"_±êµÂ’¥÷“_¡“__‘_Ó ’¥Ï“ùü’ÄÛ“_« “_Ô“ÜÂ“ù÷ “Ïã“_÷’¥Ï “µÏ“ÄÅ“ù÷ “Á¡ê±«“ùã ê¡Û“_ã “__’"
"This sentence is fine and searchable, but a few non unicode äóî donäó»t popup"                                                                                     
" This is a regular sentence of course"                                                                                                                                   
" another sentence, but with comma"                                                                                                                                       
" but what happens with question marks?"                                                                                                                                  
" or perhaps an exclamation mark!"                                                                                                                                       
end

generate tag = ustrregexm(var1, "^[A-Za-z0-9 ,.?!]*$")

. list tag, separator(0)

     +-----+
     | tag |
     |-----|
  1. |   0 |
  2. |   0 |
  3. |   1 |
  4. |   1 |
  5. |   1 |
  6. |   1 |
     +-----+
```

Another possibility is to use a regular expression to exclude any rows that do not have any alphabetic and numeric characters, a solution which in this case covers both required cases:

```
clear
input str168 var1
"_±êµÂ’¥÷“_¡“__‘_Ó ’¥Ï“ùü’ÄÛ“_« “_Ô“ÜÂ“ù÷ “Ïã“_÷’¥Ï “µÏ“ÄÅ“ù÷ “Á¡ê±«“ùã ê¡Û“_ã “__’"
"This sentence is fine and searchable, but a few non unicode äóî donäó»t popup"                                                                                     
" This is a regular sentence of course"                                                                                                                                   
" another sentence, but with comma"                                                                                                                                       
" but what happens with question marks?"                                                                                                                                  
" or perhaps an exclamantion mark!"                                                                                                                                       
"¥Ï“ùü’ÄÛ“_« “_Ô“ÜÂ“ù÷ "                                                                                                                          
"¥Ï“ùü’ÄÛ hihuo"                                                                                                                                                
end

generate tag = ustrregexm(var1, "^[^A-Za-z0-9]*$")

list tag, separator(0)

     +-----+
     | tag |
     |-----|
  1. |   1 |
  2. |   0 |
  3. |   0 |
  4. |   0 |
  5. |   0 |
  6. |   0 |
  7. |   1 |
  8. |   0 |
     +-----+
```